# Get Display Data from two tables in one #Temp Table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables I want to get data from and display in one `#temp` table order by date using a stored procedure or SQL query in SQL Server.

Table 1 `DcMaster` (Delivery Callahan table - 9 columns)

```
ID  Stus    DcEntryDate     DcEntryTime             CustomerID  MasTotalQty     ByHand  VehicleNum  UserID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   DC      2018-05-07      2018-05-07 23:58:54     3           15              Sara    KGH-6678    15
2   DC      2018-05-07      2018-05-07 23:59:35     5           1200            Hamid   KGH-6678    15
3   DC      2018-05-08      2018-05-07 20:21:31     2           680             Zeeshan KGH-6678    15
4   DC      2018-05-11      2018-05-07 09:10:29     3           1000            Sara    KGH-6678    15
```

Table 2 `DcRMaster` (Delivery Callahan Return table - 10 columns)

```
ID  Stus    DcREntryDate    DcREntryTime            ReffNum CustomerID  MasTotalQty ByHand  VehicleNum  UserID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   DcR     2018-05-16      2018-05-07 23:58:54     4       3           500         Sara    KGH-6678    15
2   DcR     2018-05-19      2018-05-07 23:59:35     2       5           200         Hamid   KGH-6678    15
```

Temp table `Display Table` - I want to display in one #Temp table like this (11 columns)

```
Tr  ID  Stus    DcREntryDate    DcREntryTime            ReffNum CustomerID  MasTotalQty ByHand  VehicleNum  UserID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1   DcR     2018-05-16      2018-05-07 23:58:54     4       3           500         Sara    KGH-6678    15
2   1   DC      2018-05-07      2018-05-07 23:58:54             3           15          Sara    KGH-6678    15
3   2   DC      2018-05-07      2018-05-07 23:59:35             5           1200        Hamid   KGH-6678    15
4   3   DC      2018-05-08      2018-05-07 20:21:31             2           680         Zeeshan KGH-6678    15
5   4   DC      2018-05-11      2018-05-07 09:10:29             3           1000        Sara    KGH-6678    15
2   2   DcR     2018-05-19      2018-05-07 23:59:35     2       5           200         Hamid   KGH-6678    15
```

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Have you tried using UNION? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the UNION OR UNION ALL operator to merge your data from two tables like this(i wish that it could help you)

```
SELECT Tr,ID,Stus,DcREntryDate,DcREntryTime,NULL AS ReffNum,CustomerID,MasTotalQty,ByHand,VehicleNum,UserID
FROM DcMaster
UNION ALL
SELECT Tr,ID,Stus,DcREntryDate,DcREntryTime,ReffNum,CustomerID,MasTotalQty,ByHand,VehicleNum,UserID
FROM DcRMaster
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Also, if you want to write this to a #temp table, just wrap this in a subquery: `select * into #temp from (unionquery)`

Answer (score 1):

```
create view combine
as
SELECT Tr,ID,Stus,DcREntryDate,DcREntryTime,NULL AS ReffNum,CustomerID,MasTotalQty,ByHand,VehicleNum,UserID
FROM DcMaster
UNION ALL
SELECT   
Tr,ID,Stus,DcREntryDate,DcREntryTime,ReffNum,CustomerID,MasTotalQty,ByHand,VehicleNum,UserID
FROM DcRMaster
ORDER BY ID
go
select * into #temp from combine
go
select * from #temp
```

**1.For union of two tables with difference in number of columns to add and balancing the 
    2 tables by providing null column.**

**2.Then creating view for the query you want to get the result.**

**3.After that using copy table with valules query to create a temp table with the resulting values.**

**4.Then select statement to display the values from the #temp table.**